# Just got (Array Networks) SPX2000. What now?

Tags: web-server, hosting

I do quite a bit of webdesign and have always wanted to host my own sites and custom servers that I make in C#.  Today, somebody just gave me an **"Array Networks SPX2000"**.  It came with just the power cable and a burned CD with some pictures of itself and a couple of pdf files.  He said it worked fine, he just didn't know how to use it.

Is this something that I can use for what I want?  If so, how?  I'm used to hosting things directly from my own computer.  I've never done it from an actual server.  Is there some location for me to start learning how to handle this situation?  Some kind of tutorials for setting it up, etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: If he didn't know how to use it then how did he know that it worked fine?

Comment: @joeqwerty The company bought it only weeks before.  Apparently it was the wrong one or something.

Comment: Probably the wrong for webhosting! ;-) funny.

Comment: I get it. The assumption is that because it's new it must work fine. Still, if you don't know how to use it then you can't possibly know how it works, and therefore can't possibly know that it works correctly (I'm being pedantic, sorry).

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm going to assume they were atleast smart enough not to buy an 8 thousand dollar server that's broken.

Comment: They make you a present of a $8,000 hardware? Looks as if this fell off the back of a lorry.

Comment: They bought it for a few weeks ago for $8k, and they've already lost the user manuals, and they're not on good enough terms with their supplier to be able to return it? Smells suss.

Comment: Man.  Looking back at these old questions often make me cringe.  The guy I got it from got it second-hand with no manuals and gave it to me.  Me thinking "server!" figured I could just do whatever with it.

Bleck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a VPN appliance. In which way do you think this is connected to "webserver" and "hosting"?

The best way to start is to read the manual and to understand what a VPN appliance is.

Comment: +1 A quick search by the OP would have turned this information up, and a search for VPN after viewing the first result of the previous the rest.